# Could not get round corner working in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

Round corner is not working in `mdframed` environment although I followed the example shown in the `mdframed` package. Below is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} 
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\mdfsetup{%
   middlelinecolor=red,
   middlelinewidth=2pt,
   backgroundcolor=red!20,
   roundcorner=20pt}

   \begin{mdframed}
   \lipsum[3]
   \end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 39):

You have to pass `framemethod=TikZ` (or `framemethod=pstricks` if working with `xelatex/latex...`) option to `\usepackage{mdframed}` like

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
```

Without any options, the frame is set to `default` in which `roundcorner` is equal to `0pt`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\mdfsetup{%
   middlelinecolor=red,
   middlelinewidth=2pt,
   backgroundcolor=red!20,
   roundcorner=20pt}

   \begin{mdframed}
   \lipsum[3]
   \end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``framemethod=pstricks`` does not seem to work with XeLaTeX, but ``framemethod=TikZ`` works great.

Comment: If you read this, odds are that you really want: `\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=red,roundcorner=3pt]{ ...content... }\end{mdframed}`. It sets the frame parameters only for the content and not globally. Anyways, good solution, thanks!