# How to use mdframed to create a round cornered box?

Tags: mdframed

I am trying to wrap my text around a round cornerd box, so I chose mdframed package, for whatever reason, it doesn't do what I intend it to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\newmdenv[
roundcorner=5pt, frametitle={address} 
]{address}
\begin{address}
\begin{center}
{
\lipsum[1]
}
\end{center}
\end{address}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Check also tcolorbox. It is newer and  imuch more powerful than mdframed.

Comment: the question says --around a round cornered box-- could you please upload a handrawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151532/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to `TeX.SE`, hope this may helps you:

In your `MWE` just add the option `tikz` will solve the issue, i.e., `\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}`

Apart from the `MWE`, below are the suggestion to add the `color` into the box, if you like.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=yellow,roundcorner=5pt,backgroundcolor=yellow!10}%
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]