# how to round corners of shaded boxes

Tags: rounded-corners

I have a shaded text box looking as:

[image]

which is generated by the following code?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{bm}  % bold greek variables (boldmath)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % use: above left of, etc
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Required for the ToDo list.
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true, kerning]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}



\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}



\begin{document}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{176,224,230}%{246,243,226}
\setlength\OuterFrameSep{0pt}
\begin{shaded*}
    % \medskip 
    \textcolor{gray}{}\\
    \textcolor{gray}{\textbf{Chapter 1}}\\
    \textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
    \medskip \\   
    Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text, 
\end{shaded*}



\setlength\OuterFrameSep{0pt}
\begin{shaded*}
    % \medskip 
    \textcolor{gray}{}\\
    \textcolor{gray}{\textbf{Chapter 2}}\\
    \textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
    \medskip \\   
    Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text, 
\end{shaded*}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to round the corners while keeping rest of the visual features intact?

Comment: Please extend your code snippets to complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which we can test as they are. Do you look to `tcolorbox` package?

Comment: The updated code given does not compile. Please correct it so that it reproduces the problem.

Comment: A possible approach can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151532/could-not-get-round-corner-working-in-mdframed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `tcolorbox` makes things easier.

https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{bm}  % bold greek variables (boldmath)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % use: above left of, etc
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Required for the ToDo list.
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true, kerning]{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{Equation~(\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{176,224,230}%{246,243,226}
%\setlength\OuterFrameSep{0pt}
%\begin{shaded*}
%    % \medskip 
%    \textcolor{gray}{}\\
%    \textcolor{gray}{\textbf{Chapter 1}}\\
%    \textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
%    \medskip \\   
%    Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text, 
%\end{shaded*}
%
%
%
%\setlength\OuterFrameSep{0pt}
%\begin{shaded*}
%    % \medskip 
%    \textcolor{gray}{}\\
%    \textcolor{gray}{\textbf{Chapter 2}}\\
%    \textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
%    \medskip \\   
%    Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text,Some text, 
%\end{shaded*}


\begin{tcolorbox}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=10pt, title=\color{gray} \textbf{Chapter 1}\\ \color{red}  \textbf{SUMMARY:}]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: out2]

You did not include the environment shaded (perhaps from `framed` ?) in your code, so I commented these lines.